# No response data ajax jquery laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

CartController Method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    $data['cart_item_id'] = $product->$id;
    $data['cart_item_name'] = $product->name;
    $data['cart_item_price'] = $product->price;

    \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::add($data['cart_item_id'], $data['cart_item_name'], 1, $data['cart_item_price']);


    return Response::json(['success' => true, 'data' => $data]);
}
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.item_add').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $('.item_add').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (html) {
                alert('Hello')
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

view:

```
<a href="{{route('cart.update',$productItem->id)}}" class="item_add">
```

When Im watching network-request-response I get nothing, why don't I get data which i return from controller?

Comment: Anything in your logs? Either the webserver's or Laravel's? (storage/logs/laravel.log) I suspect your "update" handler fails for some reason...

Comment: C:\OpenServer\domains\site.loc\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: If that's out of a log, I'm sure there's more to it than that... ;)

Comment: @MacPrawn there are 66k lines in log, which part should i send? (:

Comment: Check your network tab for the response from the server. As for your logs I would suggest removing everything from it and then repeating the request.

Comment: @Ronald you can post your log here if you want: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @RossWilson http://pastebin.com/P5wcN4K4

Comment: Please show the related code in your view.

Comment: Not sure. But I think You have called .menu view somewhere in your code and the file does not exists. Because of that this code fails.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it works.
I can suggest you have forgotten to run "gulp" for your javascripts after you added ajax method in it (this is the only reason why you see nothing in "network-request-response"). Because, if ajax works then there would be a response (with or without error).